# Two threads printing char

Tags: c, pthreads

I have to wriete program

> "Bring to life two threads. First thread must write char 'a' 30000
>   times second one 'b' 25000 times.

I wrote this program but i do not know this is a good result. I expect first see 30000 times a then b when I use `pthread_join(p,NULL)`. My program write a and b randomaly it is good or not?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t f,s;
void* a(void *arg)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<30000;j++) printf("a\n");
    return NULL;
}
void* b(void *arg)
{
    int u;
    for(u=0;u<25000;u++) printf("b\n");
    return NULL;
}


int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;

        err = pthread_create(&f, NULL, &a, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
            printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");

        err = pthread_create(&s, NULL, &b, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
            printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");


    pthread_join(f, NULL);
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know about 'good' or 'bad', but that is what I would expect. This is the trouble with contrived examples that don't really achieve anything. From what you have posted it seems like you have done enough for the question.

Comment: The whole point of using threads is to have the threads running concurrently.  Since most modern systems have multiple cores, you will have actual concurrency.  Even on single core machines, it would be surprising to get all the code from one thread executed before all the code from the other, especially since the number of characters to be written is large enough to trigger systems calls (and the newlines probably trigger flushes too).  You should probably `pthread_join(s, NULL);` too.